# Variables in an array

Tags: php

I'm trying to put a mysql query into a function, however when I do a mysql_fetch_array I need to specify the row's name. How can I put a variable in a function?

```
function config($setting_name,){
    while($config_db = mysql_fetch_array(mysql_query("SELECT {$setting_name} FROM config WHERE id='1'") {
        echo $config_db['@@@@HERE@@@@'];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
while($config_db = mysql_fetch_array(mysql_query("SELECT $setting_name FROM config WHERE id='1'") {
    echo $config_db[$setting_name];
}
```

Be sure not to pass user input directly into this function.  Also, I don't think you need the curly braces, because it's not a [complex expression](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.parsing.complex).

Answer (score 0):

You can use the mysql `AS` keyword and get an alias for it. Like this:

```
    // Using MyOutput in query:
    function config($setting_name,){
        while($config_db = mysql_fetch_array(mysql_query("SELECT {$setting_name} AS Myoutput FROM config WHERE id='1'") {
            echo $config_db['Myoutput'];
        }
    }
```